# Aggregation by MLP for GIN and GCN: What is the difference?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, mlp, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

I saw the following procedure for GIN in [this link](https://mlabonne.github.io/blog/gin/)

[image]

and the code for a GIN layer is written like this:

```
self.conv1 = GINConv(Sequential(Linear(num_node_features,dim_h),
                                    BatchNorm1d(dim_h),ReLU(),
                                    Linear(dim_h,dim_h),ReLU()))
```

Is this an aggregation function inside the `Sequential(....)` or a pooling function?

```
Sequential(Linear(num_node_features,dim_h),
                                        BatchNorm1d(dim_h),ReLU(),
                                        Linear(dim_h,dim_h),ReLU()))
```

Can I do the same thing for `GCN` layer?

self.conv1 = GCNConv(Sequential(Linear(num_node_features,dim_h),
BatchNorm1d(dim_h),ReLU(),
Linear(dim_h,dim_h),ReLU()))
self.conv2 = GCNConv(Sequential(Linear(dim_h,dim_h),
BatchNorm1d(dim_h),ReLU(),
Linear(dim_h,dim_h),ReLU()))

I get the following error:

```
---> 15 self.conv1 = GCNConv(Sequential(Linear(num_node_features,dim_h),
     16                                BatchNorm1d(dim_h),ReLU(),
     17                                Linear(dim_h,dim_h),ReLU()))
     18 self.conv2 = GCNConv(Sequential(Linear(dim_h,dim_h),
     19                     BatchNorm1d(dim_h),ReLU(),
     20                     Linear(dim_h,dim_h),ReLU()))
     21 self.conv3 = GCNConv(Sequential(Linear(dim_h,dim_h),
     22                                BatchNorm1d(dim_h),ReLU(),
     23                                Linear(dim_h,dim_h),ReLU()))

TypeError: GCNConv.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'out_channels'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see `GINConv` and `GCNConv` API from `torch_geometric`.

- [GINConv()](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/nn.html#torch_geometric.nn.conv.GINConv)

  - There is a `nn` argument e.g., defined by `torch.nn.Sequential`. Therefore in the tutorial you mentioned above can use the `Sequential()` method.
- [GCNConv()](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/nn.html#torch_geometric.nn.conv.GCNConv)

  - But `GCNConv()` does not have `nn` argument.

When you wonder about a method you don't know, searching for the method in API is a good way to solve issues :)